# in three.js, PolyhedronGeometry() failed to work

Tags: three.js

I want to create a `TetrahedronGeometry` by using `polyedronGeometry()`, but it failed to work there is nothing in the scene.

```js
var vertices = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, -1],
    [-1, 0, -1],
    [-1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0]
];
var faces = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 4],
    [1, 2, 4],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [3, 0, 4]
];

var geometry = new THREE.PolyhedronGeometry(vertices, faces);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Failed to work in what sense? Edit post to add details.

Comment: Any error messages in console logs? In consideration to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/PolyhedronGeometry), seems your arrays of vertices and faces should be one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** Look at [the documentation for PolyhedronGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PolyhedronGeometry). You are not following spec in sending it faces/vertices.

`Vertices` as an argument is supposed to be an array of floats, not an array of arrays. so `[[#.#,#.#,#.#],[....]]` is incorrect because each entry of `Vertices` is an array, not a float. but `[#,#,#,#,#,#,#, .....]` will work. same is true with `faces` it reads `[0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4]` as 3 separate faces. you don't need to break them up into their own arrays.

**Second**, you try to slip a quad into the `faces` which expects triangles. So you need to break `[0, 1, 2, 3]` into `0,1,2,1,2,3`.

**Third**, you don't define the size in `PolyhedronGeometry`, I think it defaults to 1 which should be fine, but in case you're making a scene of massive/tiny scale you might need to set this yourself to make sure that it's visible and that the camera is not inside it. I can't see your camera definition, so that could be a factor.

**Last**, for debugging, I would change

`new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});`

for:

`new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00,side:THREE.DoubleSide});`

so that just in case your winding order is incorrect, you can at least see whether you're creating the correct geometry and faces. Once you have something on screen, then you can turn off doubleside and debug the winding.